# linux audit rules excluding based on type msg exe, for the su command

Tags: linux-audit

I have the below events that occur repeatedly in my audit.log.
Can someone provide the valid syntax of the rule for the audit.rules file, that would prevent these 6 specific entries?

Ideally I want the filter to apply for `type=` for the six shown below, and for `uid=0` and `auid-4294967295` and `ses=4294967295` and `exe=/bin/su` and `result=success`.

Is this remotely possible?

I am finding the flag `-F msgtype=USER_AUTH` is only good for the rule `-a exclude` and I cannot use any other flags with exclude such as `-F auid=4294967295`.  And I cannot exclude all USER_AUTH types and miss basic events.

```
node=testserver type=USER_AUTH  msg=audit(1480608618.705:570): user pid=15378 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="efadmin" exe="/bin/su" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=? res=success)'
node=testserver type=USER_ACCT  msg=audit(1480608618.705:571): user pid=15378 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting acct="efadmin"     exe="/bin/su" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=? res=success)'
node=testserver type=CRED_ACQ   msg=audit(1480608618.705:572): user pid=15378 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="efadmin"        exe="/bin/su" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=? res=success)'
node=testserver type=USER_START msg=audit(1480608618.705:573): user pid=15378 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="efadmin"   exe="/bin/su" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=? res=success)'
node=testserver type=USER_END   msg=audit(1480608618.817:574): user pid=15378 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="efadmin"  exe="/bin/su" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=? res=success)'
node=testserver type=CRED_DISP  msg=audit(1480608618.817:575): user pid=15378 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="efadmin"        exe="/bin/su" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=? res=success)'
```